# Java.lang.classcastexception: android.app.application

Tags: android, classcastexception

My problem is this: I am trying to run the program code soundclouddroid 1.2.2. https://code.google.com/p/soundclouddroid/source/browse/
But when running the program I get an error:
 `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {es.manu.sd122.soundCloudDroid/es.manu.sd122.soundCloudDroid.SoundCloudDroid}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android . app.Application`

I do not understand why you get this error, I have not changed the code provided on code.google.

Can you help me? I'm desperate.
Thanks.

```
My logcat

10-17 07:29:33.171: I/ActivityThread(327): Pub org.urbanstew.provider.soundclouddroid: es.manu.sd122.soundCloudBase.SoundCloudData
10-17 07:29:33.481: D/AndroidRuntime(327): Shutting down VM
10-17 07:29:33.481: W/dalvikvm(327): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {es.manu.sd122.soundCloudDroid/es.manu.sd122.soundCloudDroid.SoundCloudDroid}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at  android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2120)
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1668)
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at es.manu.sd122.soundCloudBase.SoundCloudBaseActivity.getSoundCloudAPI(SoundCloudBaseActivity.java:16)
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at es.manu.sd122.soundCloudBase.SoundCloudMainActivity.updateAuthorizationStatus(SoundCloudMainActivity.java:139)
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at es.manu.sd122.soundCloudBase.SoundCloudMainActivity.onResume(SoundCloudMainActivity.java:91)
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
10-17 07:29:33.491: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  ... 12 more
10-17 08:28:24.151: I/Process(327): Sending signal. PID: 327 SIG: 9
```

The code where the error:

```
SoundCloudBaseActivity.java:

package es.manu.sd122.soundCloudBase;



import org.urbanstew.soundcloudapi.SoundCloudAPI;

import android.app.Activity;



public class SoundCloudBaseActivity extends Activity
{

public SoundCloudAPI getSoundCloudAPI()
{

    return ((SoundCloudApplicationBase)getApplication()).getSoundCloudAPI();//error line 16

}

public SoundCloudApplicationBase getSCApplicationBase()
{
    return (SoundCloudApplicationBase)getApplication();
}
}

SoundCloudMainActivity.java:

public class SoundCloudMainActivity extends SoundCloudBaseActivity implements SoundCloudRequestClient
{
.
.
.
.
 public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    updateAuthorizationStatus();//error line 91
}
.
.
.
.
public void updateAuthorizationStatus()
{
    int text;

    if(getSoundCloudAPI().getState() == SoundCloudAPI.State.AUTHORIZED)//error linea 139
    {
        if(mUserName != null)
        {
            setUserName(mUserName);
            return;
        }
        getSCApplicationBase().processRequest("me", this);
        text = R.string.verifying_connection;
    }
    else
    {
        text = R.string.please_connect;
    }

    mAuthorized.setText(text);
}
```

The file manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="es.manu.sd122.soundCloudDroid"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <!--   <provider android:name="es.manu.sd122.soundCloudBase.SoundCloudData" android:authorities="es.manu.sd122.provider.soundclouddroid">
        </provider>
-->
<provider android:name="es.manu.sd122.soundCloudBase.SoundCloudData" android:authorities="org.urbanstew.provider.soundclouddroid">
        </provider>

    <activity
        android:name="es.manu.sd122.soundCloudBase.ObtainAccessToken"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="Connect with SoundCloud">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="es.manu.sd122.soundCloudBase.ViewTracksActivity"          
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"          
        android:allowTaskReparenting="true" android:label="My Tracks">      
    </activity>

    <service android:name="es.manu.sd122.soundCloudBase.SoundCloudService"></service>



    <activity
        android:name="es.manu.sd122.soundCloudDroid.SoundCloudDroid"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="es.manu.sd122.soundCloudDroid.UploadActivity"
        android:label="Upload File To SoundCloud">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"></action>
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*"></data>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/es.manu.sd122.soundCloudDroid.UploadsActivity"></data>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


     <activity
        android:name="es.manu.sd122.soundCloudDroid.UploadsActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:allowTaskReparenting="true" android:label="View Upload Status">
    </activity>

      <activity
        android:name="es.manu.sd122.soundCloudDroid.ViewTracksActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:allowTaskReparenting="true" android:label="My Tracks">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="es.manu.sd122.soundCloudDroid.ViewOtherTracksActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:allowTaskReparenting="true" android:label="My Favorites">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="es.manu.sd122.soundCloudDroid.CustomTrackListsActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:allowTaskReparenting="true" android:label="Track Lists">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="es.manu.sd122.soundCloudDroid.NewArtistTracksActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:allowTaskReparenting="true" android:label="Search for Artists">
    </activity>


</application>
```

If you need anything else feel free to ask. Thank you again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've created a custom Application type, you need to specify it in your manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="es.manu.sd122.soundCloudBase.SoundCloudApplicationBase"
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, here you need to return `SoundCloudAPI` object but you returning `SoundCloudApplicationBase` ,

```
public SoundCloudAPI getSoundCloudAPI()
{

    return ((SoundCloudApplicationBase)getApplication()).getSoundCloudAPI();//error line 16

}
```

So try to do like this,

```
 public SoundCloudAPI getSoundCloudAPI()
    {

        return ((SoundCloudAPI)getApplication()).getSoundCloudAPI();//error line 16

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've posted the manifest code of the SoundCloud *library project*, which suggests you may be trying to run that directly. That's not how it is intended to work.

In stead, check out both `SoundCloudBase` and `SoundCloudDroid`, and make sure the former is set up as an **Android Library Project** and that the latter has a reference to it. After that, run `SoundCloudDroid`. As you can see in the manifest of that project, it correctly declares the application 'name' attribute, which is the class extending `Application` that gets instantiated at runtime:

```
android:name="SoundCloudApplication"
```

If you don't know how to set up `SoundCloudBase` as an Android Library Project, have a look here:

- http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject
- http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects

---

Edit: Looks like my initial statement wasn't fully correct, because the manifest isn't the one included in `SoundCloudBase`. It is, however, missing the application name attribute, which is the direct cause for the exception thrown. It's not unlikely that all you need to change is add in that attribute and make sure it points to the right location (i.e. use the fully qualified path name if you're unsure).

Answer (score -1):

An application class cannot be converted to another types by typecasting.